# How to make changes to the database without having to uninstall APK every time?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public class ProjectConstants {
    public static final String myDbName = "ContactsDatabase.db";
    public static final String myTableName = "ContactDetails";
   // public static final String myTableName = "ContactDetails1";
    public static final String nameColumn = "ContactName";
    public static final String numberColumn = "ContactNumber";
}
```

First I create a contact application with Table Name : **ContactDetails**
Then I do all the adding, editing and deleting operations over that database table. Say I have 15 contact details in that database table named **ContactDetails**.

Now in the above code snippet I make 2 changes:
I comment this line

```
//public static final String myTableName = "ContactDetails";
```

And I uncomment this line

```
public static final String myTableName = "ContactDetails1";
```

Now if I run the code, the App crashes.

My learning from Stack Overflow has crudely taught me 2 things to ponder

1.

> Remember to uninstall and then reinstall your app so the onCreate
>   method is called again and the database recreated.

2.

> If the database is created for the first time, the onCreate method is
>   called in the helper class, otherwise onUpgrade is called.

My subclass that extends SQLiteOpenHelper class looks like this,

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String SQLCreateEntries =
            "CREATE TABLE " + ProjectConstants.myTableName + " (" +
                    ProjectConstants.nameColumn + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    ProjectConstants.numberColumn + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
    private static final String SQLDeleteEntries = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ProjectConstants.myTableName;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, String.valueOf(name), null, version);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLCreateEntries);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLDeleteEntries);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
```

Now if I follow the instruction in the 1st quote block by uninstalling and reinstalling the application every time I mess with the database, the app never crashes. 
But if I revert back to the original database,(then I do this uninstalling and reinstalling the application) obviously my data in the database do not exist anymore.

As mentioned above my Database table named **"ContactDetails"** which held 15 contacts will no more have that data now.

But I want that 15 contacts to stay intact inside my database Table **"ContactDetails"**.

Is there anyway to make changes to the database without having to uninstalling-reinstalling apk and without losing the previous data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write SQL Commands and execute block of SQL commands with different version of code on OnUpgrade() of Helper class as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLDeleteEntries);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        switch(i){
           case 1:
               <commands for version 1>
               break;
           case 2:
                <commands for version 2>
                break;
    }
```

You can write the swich cases as per version of applications. you can write different block of SQL commands as you want to execute on different version of applications.